# Kentico 9 e-commerce order ID - reseed / change starting order number

Tags: e-commerce, kentico

From this point on, I would like my order numbers to begin counting up from, say, 1000.  How can I configure Kentico to use 1000 for the next order that is placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have order numbers above 999 right now, there are a few (non-elegent) things you could do.

- Create a manual entry of an order in the `com_order` table with an OrderID of 1000
- Update the Identity Seed on the OrderID column to 1000 in the `com_order` table

Neither are the best solution but they work and should be done in a dev environment prior to doing it on a live environment first.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use OrderID for "numbering" of your orders in the first place. This is a database field that is managed by database engine and can differ between environments. The OrderID is also not related to your business.

Kentico has **Invoice number** which is unique for each order and you should always use this in your business because you can be sure that this field instead.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read about [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms176057.aspx) command. The last example will help you)